# GitHub Username Change Breaks GitHub Page

Tags: github, github-pages

I had a GitHub account named "ericthelam73" and a subsequent website along with it (at ericthelam73.github.io). I set up A Records to link it and ericblam.com, as specified on [GitHub's help page](https://help.github.com/articles/tips-for-configuring-an-a-record-with-your-dns-provider/).

Recently, I changed my username to "ericblam". I moved the repo ericthelam73.github.io to ericblam.github.io as well. It seemed to have worked.

Every now and then, when I try going to ericblam.com or even ericblam.github.io, nothing happens. It is like I entered nothing into the browser. The other day this happened, but after a little while I was once again able to access my web page.

Is there a reason for this behavior? Did I forget to change something during the migration from one username to another?

Comment: It works here. `ericblam.github.io` does a clean redirect to `ericblam.com`.

Comment: It seems to work now. I think I had an extra A Record and then needed to clear my cache.